# django Pinax Kaleo - Error django_user_accounts wont install

Tags: python, django, pinax

I'm creating a project on django and I need a django app with a friendship service. It look that pinax kaleo is the app. I installed the app and it's dependencies using pip install. All the modules install except for the django-user-accounts. When I do sudo manage.py syncdb, I get:

```
ImportError: No module named django_user_accounts
```

These is what I have on my python library:

```
django_user_accounts-1.0b14-py2.7.egg-info
django_user_accounts-1.0b15-py2.7.egg
```

Here is my install app settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'login',
    'signup',
    'bootstrap_toolkit',
    'kaleo',
    'pinax_theme_bootstrap',
    'django_forms_bootstrap',
    'django_user_accounts',





    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Comment: Is `django_user_accounts` on your Python path? If you installed it via sudo, that's a different user and the module may not be where you expect.

Comment: I installed the other modules the same way and they are all in the python path

Answer (score 0):

Change `django_user_accounts` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` to just `account`.

http://django-user-accounts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html